# Reading files to bytes not working properly in project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird problem. I am making a C# MVC application which generates PDF's and offers them for download with a download button.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string url = (string)TempData["url"];

    byte[] thePdf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(url);

    return File(thePdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

All of a sudden I can't properly convert a PDF file to `byte[]`, either with `File.ReadAllBytes()` or with a `MemoryStream` (or any other stream).

When I used a `MemoryStream` I got an `InvalidOperationException` on both the `ReadTimeOut` and `WriteTimeOut`.

I implemented the code mentioned above in a new C# MVC Project and there everything worked fine. So the issue must be with the project that i'm working in.

Comment: SO can't help if you can't show code problem as [MCVE], especially if you only show code that works correctly.

Comment: What is the value of url?

Comment: I can swear I've seen completely identical question but from another SO user during last few days.

Comment: @Braham lendon did you try my answer? is it your required?

Answer (score 0):

If your url is remote url, you should use `WebClient` to download data like below.

I tried to reproduce your code and it worked.

```
 public ActionResult Download()
        {
            string url = (string)TempData["url"];

            url = "http://www.iuh.edu.vn/Tuyensinh/QC/TomTatQuyCheThiTHPT2018.pdf";

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // read data
                byte[] thePdf = client.DownloadData(url);

                return File(thePdf, "application/pdf");

            }

            //byte[] thePdf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(url);

            //return File(thePdf, "application/pdf");
        }
```

In cshtml:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.location.href='/YourController/Download'" />
```